# How to show $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}^n $?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Can someone please give me a hint on how I can show  $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}^n$? Any hint would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This is called extension of scalars (and in this case also *complexification*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that two mathematical objects are isomorphic, the first approach that one should try is to find an isomorphism between the two objects.

In this case, we have two complex vector spaces and we need a linear map.  The "natural" linear map to take in this context is the $f:\Bbb R^n \otimes \Bbb C \to \Bbb C^n$ satisfying
$$
f(x \otimes z) = zx
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and $z \in \Bbb C$.  It remains to be shown that $f$ is linear and bijective.

---

To show that $f$ is surjective, it suffices to note that
$$
x + iy = f(x \otimes 1 + y \otimes i).
$$
The tricky part is showing that $f$ is injective, which requires dealing with the definition of the tensor product.

An easy approach in this case is to note that every element of $\Bbb R^n \otimes \Bbb C$ can be expressed in the form $x \otimes 1 + y \otimes i$.  With that, it suffices to show that $f(x \otimes 1 + y \otimes i) = 0 \iff x=y=0$.

Comment: What I was hoping was hints on how to show this map is bijective, thankyou!

Comment: Then that's the kind of context you should have included with your question, which you should know given that you have been active on the site for several years.

Comment: Another approach is to invoke the Universal property of tensor products. They can be employed to show the bijectivity of $f$ here, but in fact we can verify directly that $\mathbb{C}^n$ along with the bilinear map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^n \ :  \ (x, z) \mapsto zx$ has the universal property of $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ and thus is isomorphic to it.